# Wave equation - Cases where separation of variables doesn't work

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, acoustics

Separation of variables combined with the Fourier's theorem is the most common technique of solving **D'Alembert's** wave equation:

$$
\Delta\Phi-\frac{1}{c_0^2}\frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial t^2}=0
$$

$$
\Phi\left(x,y,z,t \right)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)T(t) \equiv R(r)\Theta(\theta)Z(z)T(t) \equiv \  ...
$$

It's definitely not the most general method, but it's very useful and for many applications very well satisfactory (e.g. with the standing waves assumption).

Is there any (simple & easy) case where this method can't be used or (better), in an opposite point of view, a phenomenon that can't be described using this method? Feel free to name more of them, preferably with elaborated maths.

**Note:** I am well aware that such a case can be mathematically constructed, but I am aiming for motivation from physics itself.

Comment: Neither separation of variables or Fourier transformations are actual solutions to real wave problems. All they do is to transform one difficult problem into another, equally difficult one. Even with perfectly linear media the difficulty of the solution lies in the boundary conditions, not in the propagation of linear waves trough the bulk. Are there equations that are even harder to solve? Yes, there are, but the assumption that the above method is actually some sort of solution to a linear wave equation is utterly naive.

Comment: I can't fully agree. Physics is essentially a science of models, not reality itself. That's more than correct. But that is not the point. The point is to find a simple model case, if you prefer, in which separation of variables doesn't work because of model atributes.

Comment: You assignment for tomorrow is to give me an explicit formula for the spectrum of an arbitrary closed region in space with perfectly reflecting boundary conditions. :-)

Comment: How do you know I am about to spend half a day in a train to Vienna with not much to do? :-) But since I know that there is no more ugly shape on which resulting Helmholtz equation is separable than oblate spheroid, I think I pass. :-) But don't you have any other case than disgusting boundaries?

Comment: I have the message that the advanced solution theory for linear operators fills a good size mathematics library to the brim these days. Just saying...

Comment: I think you won't be able to apply separation of variables to a wave equation in [mandelbulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbulb)-shaped cavity with perfectly reflecting boundary conditions in _any_ coordinates you choose.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is thoroughly discussed in Chapter 5, volume 1 of Morse and Feshbach.  Depending on the coordinate system, the PDE might be fully separable, partially separable or non-separable.  M&F show the details for the Helmholtz equation (the temporal FT of D'Alembert) in over a dozen coordinate systems.  As was pointed out in the comments, one key issue is the application of the boundary conditions.  So if your BC are applied on one of the separable coordinates, then great simplification is achieved.  You still have to solve the ODE's for the separated problem, which can be very complex.  There's no real physics here though.  If your boundary happens to be separable, then OK.